# Check which list element have been clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check which `li` have been clicked in the unordered list. only the first `li` seems to work becouse it will alert 0 but rest of the `li` wont respond with an alert. `Nodelist` should contain element 0,1,2. Raw javascript only.

HTML

```
<ul class="slideshow-buttons">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Javasript

```
var $ = function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

var knappar = $('.slideshow-buttons').getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < knappar.length; i++) {
    var knapp = knappar[i];
    knapp.onclick = knappTryck;
}
```

Problem seems to be inside `knappTryck`

```
function knappTryck(){

    var childs = $('.slideshow-buttons').getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var c = 0; c < childs.length; i++) {
        if (this == childs[c])
        alert (c);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you forgot curly-braces around the `if (this == childs[c])`; the `break` always fires.

Comment: Yeah i noticed thanks i forgot brakets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
for (var c = 0; c < childs.length; i++) {
```

you use element `c` to parse the vector but you increment `i`. Replace `c` with `i` or the other way around

Also add braces to the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, make it 100% with jQuery :)
This will work :)

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slideshow-buttons li").live("click", function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
});
```

Comment: Im not using Jquery. I made a selector with dollar sign as tager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < knappar.length; i++) {
    var knapp = knappar[i];
    knapp.onclick = (function(i){
        return function(){
            console.log(i, this); // this is the li you clicked, and i is the index
        }
    })(i);
}
```